# Lightbox will not play video after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, fancybox, lightbox

I have an embedded YouTube video on my site that plays in a lightbox. When an user clicks the link the video plays fine the first time. If the user closes the lightbox then tries to click the link for the video again the lightbox loads but no video plays. It shows a blank screen.

Any ideas what is going on?

Here is the code:

**Link:**

```
<a id="playvid" href="#video"><img src="/image" width="70" alt="Extra 1" /></a
```

**DIV with Video:**

```
div style="display:none"><div id="video" style="width:420; height:345;">
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/..."
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
$j("a.fancybox").fancybox();
$j("a#playvid").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

I am using Fancybox 1.3.4

Comment: Which plugin are you using? There are a lot of lightbox-like plugins out there. Which version are you using?

Comment: Fancybox 1.3.4 - Edited question to include this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, than problem is pretty simple. Because of what fancybox does internally when you close the fancybox (it clears "src" attribute for any iframes it finds in the contents it displays). The second time you want to see the video the src attribute has been cleared so you don't see anything.

Solution is to either hack into the fancybox src and comment out the line responsible for clearing the "src" attribute of an iframes) or ... hmm I don't know what else, I would have to dig in deeper.

Comment: Thanks, I can leave it as is vs digging into the code. I was trying to make it as easy as possible vs reloading the page. Thanks for your help. =>

Comment: The example with an iframe on fancybox page is working all right, so maybe the solution would be to simply define *type* option as *iframe* ? As can be seen in example on fancybox page: `$("#various5").fancybox({'type': 'iframe'});`